# Error 91 Object variable ... not set when referencing Excel after creating the Excel application

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have several machines running MS Office 2013 with Windows 10.

In an Access database there is code to create several Excel worksheets in a single workbook. This worked until recently, now some machines throw an error.

```vb
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objReportDataWrkbk As Excel.Workbook

On Error Resume Next
' Try first to use an existing instance.
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo Err_ExportExternalReferralDataToExcel
objExcel.Visible = False
```

The line `objExcel.Visible = False` causes the error

> Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

If I remove the line to make Excel invisible the next line that uses `objExcel` will throw the same error.
A references is set to the Excel object library.
I tried with Excel open and closed. The error still occurs.

I can manually open Excel and use `DoCmd.OutputTo` to output a query to Excel. (I cannot use the `DoCmd` method in the scenario I am having the issue with.)

Comment: It seems that the `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` fails. Change your code: Imediately after `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, write `On Error Goto 0`. Change the `If` to `If objExcel  is Nothing Then`. That should show you any error that happens when Excel coudn't be started

Comment: `objExcel` is null (Nothing)!

Comment: Thanks, will not be able to get access to the machines until tomorrow and will change code as suggested to get more detail on the error.

Comment: Thankyou @FunThomas for the prompt to change the error trapping.  I got 'Error 429 Active X component can't create object'.  Changed my code to late binding and the error did not occur - which led me to this MS article and the solution being in the installation of Excel (which is why it worked on some machines.)  [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications-b6070e15-ea78-4349-2751-72bdb5f186f7)